# What regular expression would I use to remove everything after the second backslash?

Tags: c#, regex

Using C# I write PowerShell output to a text file. The output within the text file looks like this:

```
Caption     : USB Mass Storage Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_2188&PID_0754\000000000001
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_2188&PID_0754\000000000001
Status      : OK

Caption     : USB Input Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_187C&PID_0528\16.0
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_187C&PID_0528\16.0
Status      : OK

Caption     : USB Input Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_0BDA&PID_4042&MI_03\D&19A846&0&0003
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_0BDA&PID_4042&MI_03\D&19A846&0&0003
Status      : OK

Caption     : USB Input Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_060B&PID_7A01&MI_03\D&10693F50&0&0003
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_060B&PID_7A01&MI_03\D&10693F50&0&0003
Status      : OK

Caption     : USB Input Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_060B&PID_7A01&MI_02\D&10693F50&0&0002
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_060B&PID_7A01&MI_02\D&10693F50&0&0002
Status      : OK
```

I'd like to remove everything after the second backslash for DeviceID and PNPDeviceID so that I end up with this:

```
Caption     : USB Mass Storage Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_2188&PID_0754\
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_2188&PID_0754\
Status      : OK

Caption     : USB Input Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_187C&PID_0528\
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_187C&PID_0528\
Status      : OK

Caption     : USB Input Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_0BDA&PID_4042&MI_03\
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_0BDA&PID_4042&MI_03\
Status      : OK

Caption     : USB Input Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_060B&PID_7A01&MI_03\
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_060B&PID_7A01&MI_03\
Status      : OK

Caption     : USB Input Device
DeviceID    : USB\VID_060B&PID_7A01&MI_02\
PNPDeviceID : USB\VID_060B&PID_7A01&MI_02\
Status      : OK
```

It seems like using a regular expression would be the best approach but I have no idea of how to go about achieve the results that I want. I'm open to other suggestions and/or advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think regular expressions are the right tool here? I would encourage you not default to using regular expressions when much simpler string manipulation techniques will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

`line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)`

`LastIndexOf()` returns -1 if the query value is not found.

Answer (score 0):

/[A-z0-9]+\\/g will match in this question

Test : USB\VID_0BDA&PID_4042&MI_03\D&19A846&0&0003

Result : USB\VID_0BDA&PID_4042&MI_03\

Answer (score 0):

`.(?<!\\)\\.(?<!\\)\\(?<After>.*)` Is an arbitrary gimme everything after the second backslash (double \ to escape within regex - inside code in quotes you may have to go quad slash depending on language)